# Featherlight external html opening (AJAX)

Tags: ajax, featherlight.js

I'm sorry but I spent long time but can't figure out what is wrong to pop-up the other html file with the Featherlight. The manual says nothing additional so I will be happy if you will guide me what's wrong:

```
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.5.0/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.5.0/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<a href="http://www.htmliseasy.com/popup/popup1.html .jQuery-Selector" data-featherlight="ajax">Open Ajax Content</a>
<br>
Ver2
<br>
<a href="#" data-featherlight="http://www.htmliseasy.com/popup/popup1.html .jQuery-Selector">Open Ajax Content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class in your target html page

So within http://www.htmliseasy.com/popup/popup1.html
there should be a content here

(you can rename "jQuery-Selector" whatever you wish...)